# (keypress) event in ionic 4 not triggering

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, events, ionic4

According to this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#events ionic supports **keypress** event which is working fine in the browser but in mobile device it is not triggering

html

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Default Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input (keypress)="test($event)"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

ts

```
test(event){

console.log(event);
 e.preventDefault();
}
```

> the above code works fine in ionic serve not in mobile device

According to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event keypress is depricated i am not understanding

> Events i tried: keypress, keydown, keyup, ionblur, ionChange, input,..etc
>   Either it is not working or it or preventdefault is not working

Comment: Facing the same issue. neither (ionInput) nor (keypress) works. Did you find a way in order for it to work?

Answer (score 5):

According to your own first link I guess you are looking for the event `ionInput    Emitted when a keyboard input ocurred.` :

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Default Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input (ionInput)="test($event)"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: no i dont want any value to be displayed as you can see i have given `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: And `event.preventDefault()` doesn't work with `ionInput`? If it doesn't I'd try catching the keyboard events with a `@HostListner()` but it may not be the cleanest way

Answer (score 2):

> Pass $event to your event handler. The $event is a DOM KeyboardEvent.

```
<input type=text (keypress)="eventHandler($event)">

eventHandler(event) {
   console.log(event, event.keyCode, event.keyIdentifier);
}
```

If you know which KeyboardEvent property you want, you can pass that into your event handler:

```
<input type=text (keypress)="eventHandler($event.keyCode)">

eventHandler(keyCode) {...}
```

Comment: the above code works fine in browser as i have mentioned it is not firing in mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Use readonly attribute with ionInput event from @Gilsidoo answer, or other event as keyPress which might work in ur case.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Default Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input readonly (ionInput)="test($event)"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**EDIT**: I suppose onInput with readonly will not work, try using keyup may be.